# Unit test structure focused on responsibilities

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm not going to ask what is the best unit test structure or how to do it again. There are already enough questions about it. Instead I'd like you to tell me what else I could consider in the structure that I came up with (borrowing from other ideas and adding new ones).

I've been thinking about how can I improve my test structure because after writing a few tests it was becoming harder and harder to see what cases I've already covered and which are still missing. A long list of test methods didn't really show what features they were actually testing. They were testing some cases but what kind of cases? They are mostly too unspecific to me. I wanted them to be a documentation of what is required for a class/method to work and how it works rather then what it does if it doesn't or does if it works.

So I flipped the logic and instead of writing what really happens I write what the class/method must recognize as an incorrect or correct usage.

To implement it I added two new *layers* to the test structure *prerequisite tests* and *usage tests*. This allows me to better keep in mind what I have already tested and what is missing. Let's try it on the following (simplified) example:

```
public class Configuration
{
     public static XDocument LoadConfiguration(string fileName)
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

         if (!File.Exists(fileName)) throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName);

         return XDocument.Load(fileName);
     }
}
```

To test it I first define (if necessary) some tests for testing the prerequisites that must be satisfied before it is even possible to work with a class or method.

Then I test the different possible usages of the class or method.

```
[TestClass]
public class ConfigurationTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class LoadConfiguration_TestPrerequisites
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void FileNameMustNotBeNull()
        {
            // assert that ArgumentNullException is thrown when fileName is null
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void FileNameMustExist()
        {
            // assert that FileNotFoundException is thrown when file doesn't exist
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class LoadConfiguration_TestUsage
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void MustImportValidXml()
        {
            // assert that configuration was loaded
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void MustNotImportInvalidXml()
        {
            // assert that some other exception was thrown on invalid xml
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: What other key responsibilities I might be missing here besides prerequisites and usage? Somehow I'm not yet entirely happy with it and my gut tells me that I've overlooked something.

My goal is also to describe (name) the tests more naturally so they better show class/method's responsibilities and not what happens. I find it's easier to understand *FileNameMustNotBeNull* than *Throws_FileNotFoundException*. because the implementation may change (I could decide to return a null value if it the file name was null) but it still cannot be null.

Comment: Separating your tests into logical groups is something that is independent of how you name your tests. Even if you don't separate your tests into groups like Prerequisites/Usage/etc., you can use names that describe the purpose of the test rather than how the tested code should be implemented. The latter way of naming can easily result in more fragile testcases as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some broad categories of tests that might be what you need:

- handling invalid input (what you call *prerequisites*)
- correctness of happy-path logic (what you call *usage*) - this one may be large enough to be worth of decomposing further, but it's case-specific
- handling edge cases (where the input is at the edges of valid range)
- handling negative cases (testing that something undesired doesn't happen)

I wouldn't call them responsibilities though. A module should have only one responsibility (it's function).

Validation of prerequisites is not some 'secondary' responsibility of a module; it's only a way to ensure that the module is able to process the input (perform it's function) correctly.

Comment: This sounds sensible although prerequisites are for me not the same as invalid data. To me a prerequisite must be met to so that a method can begin its work (here file name must not be null and the file must exist). But I admit it's not easy to diversify. Maybe I should call it _defences_ instead of prerequisites ;-) I think prerequisites is a good name. However you're right that usage is a wide concept and perhaps it would be better to split into invalid and valid input.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your understanding of prerequisites and think it's a good name (and widely used for this kind of thing).